# GETDATE () statement

Tags: sql

Running the following :

```
GETDATE() AND datepart(hour, time) >= 5 AND datepart(hour, time) < 18
```

Will this get me 5am to 5pm? Also, Is there anything special to get 5pm to 5am, wrapping around midnight. Will there be two statements needed, 1 for before midnight, and one from 12:00 to 5am?

I run the below and sometime the return is null.
Does this make any sense??

```
WHERE time >= GETDATE() AND datepart(hour, time) >= 5 AND datepart(hour, time) < 18
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data?  I dont quite know what your looking for.  Can you rephrase what it is you want your select to do but without using SQL syntax

Comment: You aren't really specifying what you want. You are just telling us what you tried and asking us if its correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to validate a time of the day, if it exists between 5am and 6pm, then you may try something like this.

```
declare @d datetime = GETDATE()
select DATEPART(hh, @d)
where @d >= GETDATE() and datepart(hour, @d) >= 5 AND datepart(hour, @d) < 18;
```

Then at 1 pm, it gives 13.

In case of previous day, it doesnt display anything, like:

```
 set @d = DATEADD(dd, -1, @d)
 select DATEPART(hh, @d)
where @d >= GETDATE() and datepart(hour, @d) >= 5 AND datepart(hour, @d) < 18;
```

My two cents!